# How do I iterate a function which has 3 variables?

Tags: python

I have this function which is defined by 3 variables xvalue, P, C

```
we have f(xvalue, P, C) = a formula
```

This formula gives me an approximation for my data. So, I want this function(which gives a list) to be very close to the data values.

All the 3 variables take 29 values so I use a linespace command for all 3.

This is the code I have written.

```
G = 6.687*(10**(-11))
pie = 3.14159265358979
xvalue = np.linspace(8, 37, 29)*(3.086*(10**(19)))
def f(xvalue, P, C):
    return ((G*(((2*pie*(C)**3*P*((2*(xvalue+C)**2) * (np.log(xvalue+C)) +4*C*xvalue + 3*(C)**2 ))/(xvalue+C)**2) - (2*pie*(C)**3*P*(2*np.log(C) + 3))))**(1/2))/(xvalue)**(1/2)
f( (np.linspace(8, 37, 30)*(3.086*(10**(19)))), (np.linspace(5, 10, 30)*(10**(-20)))  , (np.linspace(2, 9, 30)*(10**(19))))
```

And the result I get is

```
array([ 41057.48335783,  46766.86571009,  52630.23811206,  58644.17375691,
        64805.45233656,  71111.04022756,  77558.07341632,  84143.842609  ,
        90865.78013739,  97721.44837086, 104708.52940819, 111824.81586818,
       119068.2026304 , 126436.67940272, 133928.32401215, 141541.29633103,
       149273.83276362, 157124.24122895, 165090.89658431, 173172.23644133,
       181366.75733289, 189673.01119427, 198089.60212662, 206615.18341451,
       215248.45477286, 223988.15980131, 232833.08362655, 241782.05071537,
       250833.92284304, 259987.59720332])
```

An array with 29 values.
But, I want to get more than 29 values.
To elucidate, the values I am getting are

```
 f(x[0], P[0], C[0])
 f(x[1], P[1], C[1])
 f(x[2], P[2], C[2])
 f(x[3], P[3], C[3])....
 f(x[29], P[29], C[29])
```

However, for greater approximation for my data, I want the the iteration of individual elements like this;

```
f(x[0], P[0], C[0]) 
 f(x[0], P[1], C[0])
 f(x[0], P[2], C[0])
 f(x[0], P[3], C[0]).....
 f(x[0], P[29], C[0])
```

and then the computer takes the next set of values

```
 f(x[1], P[0], C[0]) 
 f(x[1], P[1], C[0])
 f(x[1], P[2], C[0])
 f(x[1], P[3], C[0])....
 f(x[1], P[29], C[0])
```

So this goes on until x reaches 29. But, C is still zero. So I need to repeat the process again but this time I need to have the value of C as 1.

I don't know how to implement this process in code. Is there a simpler way to do this instead of having to manually re-enter values?

Comment: FYI, you can just write `6.687e-11` and `3.086e19` instead of `6.687*(10**(-11))` and `3.086*(10**(19))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out itertools https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html - you are looking for

```
import itertools as it

prods = it.product(range(30), repeat=3)
for prod in prods:
    print(prod)
```

it will first increment c, then b, then a

Comment: If you need the arguments in a certain order, you can pass `x[prod[2]],  P[prod[1]], C[prod[0]]` for example - which has the reversed order in that you first incrementing a, then b, then c.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it and try the code

Comment: Once I get the Cartesian product, how do I input each product into the formula?

Comment: You can access each of the elements via index 0, 1 and 2. Then you input your arrays like before, but you use one element from the prod array above as the index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.meshgrid` for this.

```
import numpy as np


X = np.linspace(-4, 4, 11)
Y = range(-5, 6)
Z = range(-3, 4)

x_1, y_1, z_1 = np.meshgrid(X, Y, Z)
  
for x, y, z in zip(x_1.ravel(), y_1.ravel(), z_1.ravel()):
    print(x, y ,z)
```

To evaluate the function in all the points is simple:

```
f(x_1.ravel(), y_1.ravel(), z_1.ravel())
```

Comment: this returns non-integer values for me. i don't think they are usable for indexing an array.

Comment: You can substitute the list of values by anything. You can use `X = range(-4, 5)` if you need integers.